# Second drive not appearing in “Install Ubuntu Alongside Windows Boot Manager”

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04

I have an SSD which contains my windows and some programs, and my HDD which stores games. I want to install Ubuntu to the other drive, while keeping my games. 20.04

Comment: Try disabling fast boot. Shrink the game drive partition and make room for Ubuntu. Do not format that area. Do all these from within Windows. Then try again.

Comment: Fast boot is disabled. I shrunk the drive to make a 100gb partition of unallocated space. When I go into the setup and press install alongside windows, it sets it automatically to a drive, showing an install now button instead of a continue button.

Comment: That sounds about right. If my comment answered your question, I can write it as an answer, so that you can accept it. That will help others. If not, please update your question.